# How to concisely unwrap an algebraic data type in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, algebraic-data-types

Is there a good way to concisely unwrap an algebraic data type in OCaml?  For example, consider the following code that defines two different types of mathematical functions

```
type ftype =                                                         
    | Quadratic of {alpha : float; a : float array; aa : float array}
    | General of {eval : float array->float}
type myfn = {                                                                   
    nvar : int;
    typ : ftype}  
let f = {                                                                       
    nvar = 2;                                                                   
    typ = General {eval = fun x-> x.(0) +. x.(1)}}
```

For debugging purposes, it sometimes nice to just evaluate a function or check its values in the top level.  However, if we want to evaluate f, we require a code that looks like

```
let x = [| 1.; 2. |]
let y = match f.typ with General(f) -> f.eval(x)
```

This is kind of ugly and a pain to type especially if the layering is several layers deep.  I'd like to define some kind of syntax such as

```
let y = f.typ.General.eval(x)
```

And, yes, the code is not safe and this will not compile.  That said, something close to this would be nice for debugging purposes, so that we don't have to write a lengthy piece of code to unwrap a value.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can destructure with a let binding: `let y = let { typ = General(f) } = f in f.eval(x)`. Arguably less ugly, but certainly not shorter in this case. It will however deal better with nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just for debugging purposes, you can always write:

```
let { typ = General { eval; } ; } = f in
let y = eval x in
...
```

Of course, the compiler will print you a warning 8 (non-exhaustive pattern matching).

I don't think you can do more concise, sum types are meant to be readable and safe. Not to be quick, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you play with your code in the toplevel it is perfectly fine to use refutable (i.e., incomplete) patterns, e.g.,

```
let [1;3;5] = List.filter is_odd [1;2;3;4;5]
```

To prevent the toplevel from spoiling your experience with warnings, just disable them with

```
#warnings "-P";;
```

(or "-8", that's the same, and don't forget to type the leading `#` it is a part of the directive, not the prompt).